# Unable to access firebase using w5500 ethernet module with arduino

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ethernet

I'm able to fetch time from NTP server as well as creating a UDP stream but while accessing the real-time firebase, I am confused, how to initiate an HTTP request considering the Auth key.

```
  String HOST_NAME = "https://*******-*****-*******-****.firebaseio.com";
  String key = "**********************";

  String url = HOST_NAME + "/.json?auth=" + key;
  http.begin(url);

  int httpCode = http.GET();
```

Here, on http.GET, the core panic and controller reboots. I'll be thankful if someone could help.